# Typescript file is out of date in the Chrome developer console

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

Been working on an app, and I just added a function to my typescript file and ran it.

Source maps are on.

In Chrome, press F12, browse to the script, it's showing the .ts file before I added the function. The .js file is showing my new function.

Force a refresh, delete the .map file and rebuild, ensure no other copies of that file are on the disk, close + reopen chrome, rebuild, STILL, it is showing the old copy of the file without my new function. It also doesn't appear to be executing the JS, but I cannot debug it to find out why.

Can anyone suggest how I might debug this problem?

Comment: I have had this problem before. Sometimes the old typescript file is showing up in the console, but the newer typescript file is still being used. It certainly makes it difficult to debug and verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this is a problem with Chrome's caching the map files. Doing a full wipe of the cache/internet history/etc. has resolved the problem.

Even manually requesting the .ts source file gave a cached version, as well as ctrl+f5 / shift+f5 to force a refresh, so it really is necessary to nuke this from orbit.

I'm going to add some no cache headers to see if that resolves it permanently, but it's something to be aware of it you're using source maps with typescript and chrome.